# Array is created fine in include file, but not in function

Tags: php

I have the following code which creates an array.

```
$qry="SELECT foo_id, foo1, foo2 FROM foo_table";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
extract($row);  
$my_array[$foo_id] = array('foo1' => $foo1, 'foo2'  => $foo2);
}
```

If I save this in a separate file (array.php) and then 'include' this in my code (example 1) everything works fine and $my_array can be called fine. If however I set this code up as a function (example 2) and call it from within my code and then try and use the array I get the message that $my_array has not been defined.

example 1 - displays the array

```
include 'array.php';
var_dump($my_array[1]);
```

example 2 - gets the error message Undefined variable: $my_array

```
function create_array(){
  $qry="SELECT foo_id, foo1, foo2 FROM foo_table";
  $result=mysql_query($qry);

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  extract($row);    
  $my_array[$foo_id] = array('foo1' => $foo1, 'foo2'  => $foo2);
  }
}

create_array();
var_dump($my_array[1]);
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? I'm a bit new to php so simple explanations would be appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I was just wondering if they were going to depreciate those function.  I'm a new convert to PDO, and I will never look back.  Not constructive to the problem at hand, but a +1 for suggesting PDO.

Comment: @FireCrakcer37, glad to here it. It **is** constructive to the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$my_array` being defined inside a function, doesn't exists outside that function.

Try add `return $my_array;` in `create_arry()` function.

Then call the function like this: `$my_array = create_arry();`, to store data returned by that funnction in `$my_array` variable.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!
Simple explanation and it worked perfectly. Have a biscuit on me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it about variable scope. Inside a function a variable only available in local scope of self function, unless its defined by keyword global.

```
function create_array(){
  global $my_array;
  $qry="SELECT foo_id, foo1, foo2 FROM foo_table";
  $result=mysql_query($qry);

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    extract($row);    
    $my_array[$foo_id] = array('foo1' => $foo1, 'foo2'  => $foo2);
  }
}

create_array();
var_dump($my_array[1]);
```

or better by function return value :

```
function create_array(){
  $qry="SELECT foo_id, foo1, foo2 FROM foo_table";
  $result=mysql_query($qry);

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    extract($row);    
    $my_array[$foo_id] = array('foo1' => $foo1, 'foo2'  => $foo2);
  }
  return $my_array;
}

$my_array = create_array();
var_dump($my_array[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue deals with [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

There are multiple ways to solve this, but given the name of your function, I would *expect* it `return` the array.

For example:

```
function create_array() {
  // current code

  return $my_array;
}

$arr = create_array();
var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The $my_array variable is local to the create_array function. It doesn't exist outside of create_array. If you want to use the variable outside the function, you either have to make it global with the "global" keyword (not recommended) or simply pass the array back to the main program as a return value. For example:

```
function create_array(){
  $qry="SELECT foo_id, foo1, foo2 FROM foo_table";
  $result=mysql_query($qry);

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    extract($row);    
    $my_array[$foo_id] = array('foo1' => $foo1, 'foo2'  => $foo2);
  }
    return $my_array;
}

$my_array = create_array();
var_dump($my_array[1]);
```

The way PHP variable scoping works, even if you had declared $my_array in the main program first, it would still be local to the create_array function unless you made it a global variable with the keyword "global" or passed it as a parameter to the function. It's different from some other languages, such as JavaScript, where declaring a variable in the main program automatically gives it a global scope.

As an aside, you might be able to save yourself a step when you get the data from MySQL by using the mysql_fetch_assoc function which will return the query results in an associative array, with the field names as the keys. For example,

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc())
```

will give you:

```
$row["foo_id"] = value1;
$row["foo1"] = value2;
$row["foo3"] = value3;
```

I wasn't totally clear what you were trying to do the function but I thought I would point that out.